# Mongo querying times issue in multiple environments (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, indexing, enums

I work on a project with two environments, A & B, each with its own database. My spring boot (1.5.3) application uses mongodb, where I am querying a collection based on an enum `EnumType` with values `TYPE1` and `TYPE2`.

Now, in env. A, when trying to fetch all entries where `EnumType = TYPE1`, which I can see in my database are about 2000, this takes a long time. Fetching entries where `EnumType = TYPE2` takes a normal amount of time.

In env. B, when fetching the `TYPE1` entries, which are far more (approx 2M), this takes very little to happen. Fetching the `TYPE2` entries (450 entries) takes a ridiculous amount of time.

I have added a `type_1` index in both cases (get by `EnumType` ascending), but these odd times remain, to the point where if I try to fetch the `TYPE2` entries in env B, my application crashes. Since the search logic is the same in both environments (the exact same application runs in both cases), I'm not sure what else to do in order to fix this issue.

The code is simple:

EntityController:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Entity> getAll(@RequestParam EnumType type, OffsetPageRequest page) {
    return entityService.getAll(type, page);
}
```

EntityService:

```
public Page<Entity> getAll(EnumType type, OffsetPageRequest page) {
    return entityRepository.findByCriteria(type, page);
}
```

CustomizedEntityRepository:

```
Page<Entity> findByCriteria(EnumType type, Pageable page);
```

UserProfileRepositoryImpl:

```
@Override
public Page<Entity> findByCriteria(EnumType type, Pageable page) {
    Query query = new Query().with(page);
    List<Criteria> andCriteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    andCriteriaList.add(Criteria.where("type").is(type));
    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(andCriteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[0])));
    return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(mongoTemplate.find(query, Entity.class), page, () -> mongoTemplate.count(query, Entity.class));
}
```

EnumType:

```
public enum EnumType {
    TYPE1,TYPE2;

    private EnumType() {
    }
}
```

Both applications have the same configuration files, with the only differences being the corresponding database URLs.

Comment: You can verify the usage of index in a query by generating a Query Plan (using the explain method).

Comment: Thank you. With this, I found that in env. B a compound index was used instead of the `type_1` one I had created specifically for this case. (the `Entity` has more fields than just the type). I suppose this leads to a slowed down performance, but I'm not sure if I'm correct or why this is the `winningPlan`.

Comment: When an index is used you will see a IXSCAN in the plan. A query can use a compound index, provided the index prefix fields are used in the query filter.

Comment: This does not explain why the 2M entries are fetched in a relatively small amount of time, whereas the 450 ones take forever (and break my app in the process).

Comment: "...break my app in the process" - what does the error say? There might be a clue in it.